I bought SHR Sahara AI, I can't make an exchange
I bought SHR Sahara AI and now I cannot exchange it in my wallet and on other decentralized exchangers. I exchanged it for UNISWAP, but I can't exchange it back.
I use the Phantom wallet, but nothing comes out
Please help me please


It might be a scam token. Please check the score here.
https://www.dextools.io/app/en/ether/pair-explorer/0xb6504470e50a65fe916e9763bbbdd8706f5df49d?t=1733465754363


I already realized that this is a regular honeypot, but isn't there any way to get the funds back?
 https://i.imgur.com/bOT6eDE.png
